# imagesc and imshow bug in Matlab, so weird

Tags: image, matlab

It seems my imshow and imagesc is problematic.

```
c = [1, 2; 3, 4];
imagesc(c);
```

result:

```
    Error using setdiff
    Too many input arguments.

    Error in clo (line 49)
                kids_to_delete = setdiff(findall(obj,'serializable','on','-depth',1),obj,'legacy');

    Error in cla (line 29)
    clo(ax, extra{:});

    Error in newplot>ObserveAxesNextPlot (line 125)
        cla(ax, 'reset',hsave);

    Error in newplot (line 74)
    ax = ObserveAxesNextPlot(ax, hsave);

    Error in imagesc (line 19)
        hh = image(varargin{1},'CDataMapping','scaled');
```

As I tried imshow:

```
c = [1, 2; 3, 4];
imshow(c);
```

result:

```
 Error using setdiff
    Too many input arguments.

Error in clo (line 49)
            kids_to_delete = setdiff(findall(obj,'serializable','on','-depth',1),obj,'legacy');

Error in cla (line 29)
clo(ax, extra{:});

Error in newplot>ObserveAxesNextPlot (line 125)
    cla(ax, 'reset',hsave);

Error in newplot (line 74)
ax = ObserveAxesNextPlot(ax, hsave);

Error in basicImageDisplay (line 24)
    hh = image(cdata, ...

Error in imshow (line 266)
  hh = basicImageDisplay(fig_handle,ax_handle,...
```

I am using win-64bit, MatLab R2013b now and it seems this problem happened several time and can be solved after I re-install Matlab.

Comment: Have you tried closing all figures (with `close all`)? Or re-starting Matlab?

Comment: @LuisMendo Yep, no lucks.

Comment: Try `which setdiff` - is there another file called `setdiff` on your Matlab path that shadows the built-in function?